# How to convert input string to desired(given) format using regex or arrays?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I have input string coming from user like this

```
" |appl | pinea | orang frui | vege lates"
```

and I want to convert it to this format

```
"+(appl* | pinea* | orang*) +(frui* | vege*) +(lates*)"
```

I have tried with preg_match and arrays but unable to find solution

```
$term = " |appl | pinea | orang frui | vege lates";

$term = trim($term, "| ");

$term = preg_replace("#[\| ]{2,}#", " | ", $term);

// $term value is "appl | pinea | orang frui | vege lates" after applying safe guards

// $matches = [];
// $matched = preg_match_all("#(\P{Xan}+)\|(\P{Xan}+)#ui", $term, $matches);
// var_dump($matches);

$termArray = explode(" ", $term);

foreach($termArray as $index => $singleWord) {
   $termArray[$index] = trim($singleWord);
}

$termArray = array_filter($termArray);

foreach($termArray as $index => $singleWord) {
   if($singleWord === "|") {

       $pipeIndexes[] = $index;
       $orIndexes[] = $index - 1;
       $orIndexes[] = $index + 1;

       unset($termArray[$index]);

    }

}

// desired string I am hoping for
// "+(appl* | pinea* | orang*) +(frui* | vege*) +(lates*)"
```

desired string I am hoping for
"+(appl* | pinea* | orang*) +(frui* | vege*) +(lates*)"

Comment: At a quick glance, I am tempted to say that you should be writing a parser to handle this, rather than trying to do it with regex.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Be a dear and please solve this for me. I think it falls outside of what my brain can handle

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen guess I have to find another approach. Thanks for upvote though

Comment: What makes ` |appl ` the start of a "`+` group", I kind of get `frui` has a space and the word `orang` and a space with no `|` symbol - but the `appl` doesn't match this logic. Could you explain?

Comment: @ Dean Taylor thats why these two lines to safe guard against those scenarios $term = trim($term, "| ");

$term = preg_replace("#[\| ]{2,}#", " | ", $term);

Comment: Try https://3v4l.org/0g68C

Comment: Or like this https://3v4l.org/R2gr9

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew and The fourth bird  both working fine. Thanks so much

Comment: -1 you don't explain the rules going from `" |appl | pinea | orang frui | vege lates"` to `"+(appl* | pinea* | orang*) +(frui* | vege*) +(lates*)"`

Comment: @sln came late to the party and complaining about rules. I wrote like this because user input is not always reliable and I mentioned this in code comment "// $term value is "appl | pinea | orang frui | vege lates" after applying safe guards"

Comment: @Pankaj: Whatever, your question stays unclear. Keep in mind that there's people on SO that are able to provide an answer (or a comment) without to understand the logic behind, only to win reputation points or/and for their own imaginary|virtual prestige (that is finally the same).

Comment: @Pankaj: Absolutely not, a question has to be clear and it's clearly not the case here. Also, the goal of SO is to help further users with a similar problem, but since yours isn't well defined (to not say ununderstandable), it helps nobody. That's why close votes as "unclear what is asked" are done (most of the time downvotes come with them, like a bonus). The best thing you have to do is to edit your question to **correctly** explain your problem and the rules of your replacement (as asked).

Comment: @Pankaj: Yes you are right <:)))))))))> good analysis.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I am sorry if I couldn't define the question clearly enough for you and anybody else. I just think a PHP developer or student who have used regex will understand the question just fine. If not then I am happy to discuss what you didn't understand in comment or pm.

Comment: @Pankaj - It's the principle. If you made a presentation at work with an arrow pointing from here to there. What would the presentation be for ? The applause ? I could write my answer in pure regex with an arrow pointing to it I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes you have cleaned up your input string to the following:

```
appl | pinea | orang frui | vege lates
```

#### Quick working example

https://3v4l.org/NjIai

```php
<?php

$subject = 'appl | pinea | orang frui | vege lates';

// Add the "*" in place at end
$subject = preg_replace('/[a-z]+/i', '$0*', $subject);

// Group the terms adding brackets and + sign
$result = preg_replace('/(?:[^\s|]+\s*\|\s*)*(?:[^\s|]+)/i', '+($0)', $subject);

var_dump($result);
// Outputs:
// string(53) "+(appl* | pinea* | orang*) +(frui* | vege*) +(lates*)"
```

#### Add in the `*` after each word:

```
$result = preg_replace('/[a-z]+/i', '$0*', $subject);
```

#### Group based on space

```
$result = preg_replace('/(?:[^\s|]+\s*\|\s*)*(?:[^\s|]+)/i', '+($0)', $subject);
```

#### Visualisation

[image: Regex Visualisation]

#### Human Readable

```
(?:[^\s|]+\s*\|\s*)*(?:[^\s|]+)
```

Options: Case insensitive; Exact spacing; Dot doesn’t match line breaks; ^$ don’t match at line breaks; Greedy quantifiers; Regex syntax only

- Match the regular expression below `(?:[^\s|]+\s*\|\s*)*`

  - Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `*`
  - Match any single character NOT present in the list below `[^\s|]+`

    - Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `+`
    - A “whitespace character” (any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed, next line) `\s`
    - The literal character “|” `|`
  - Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed, next line) `\s*`

    - Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `*`
  - Match the character “|” literally `\|`
  - Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed, next line) `\s*`

    - Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `*`
- Match the regular expression below `(?:[^\s|]+)`

  - Match any single character NOT present in the list below `[^\s|]+`

    - Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `+`
    - A “whitespace character” (any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed, next line) `\s`
    - The literal character “|” `|`

`+($0)`

- Insert the character “+” literally `+`
- Insert an opening parenthesis `(`
- Insert the whole regular expression match `$0`
- Insert a closing parenthesis `)`

Comment: very well explained upto the minute details. Understood it nicely. Thanks